# Hibernate org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, procedure

I searched above error message and found several questions related to, like [Object references an unsaved transient instance save the transient instance before flushing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866096/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save-the-transient-instance-befo) and [object references an unsaved transient instance - Spring, JPA Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277986/object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-spring-jpa-hibernate) and [How to fix the Hibernate "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302802/how-to-fix-the-hibernate-object-references-an-unsaved-transient-instance-save) but they don't seem like mine.

My project is Spring boot, using hibernate to interact with Oracle database.

My entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String name;
    String address;
    LocalDateTime createdAt;
    LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    // Getter
    // Setter
}
```

I have a procedure which takes a `List` of `Student` as IN parameter, and `List` of `Student` as OUT parameter, so I declare it as an `IN OUT` parameter. It works like below:

```sql
// Loop the input list 
// Each student only has name and address, id & createdAt & updatedAt are generated automatically by Oralcle
// Returning id & createdAt & updatedAt to each student
// Return the list
```

I created a SQL script to call above procedure and it works perfectly.

This is how I call the procedure from my application:

```java
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Query(value = "execute my_procedure(:covenants)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Student> saveBulk(@Param("students") List<Student> students);
}

public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public void saveBulk(List<Student> students){
        studentRepository.saveBulk(students);
    }
}
```

An exception ocurred:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.myapplication.entity.Student; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.myapplication.entity.Student
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy245.saveBulk(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to change from `@Query` to `@Procedure` and added `NamedStoredProcedureQuery` to `Student` but it does not work also.

How can I call this procedure ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `@Id` annotation in your entity. This could be the problem.

Comment: sorry I missed that part, I updated the question, I've already had @Id in source code